# BuddyPress user custom url structure , any one knows filter for bp_core_get_userlink

Tags: buddypress

i have created my custom profile template and trying to redirect users on page like this

```
www.xyz.com/my-coustom-page?id=11
```

where 11 is user id

we just want to change url of user's profile .

anyone have idea to filter `bp_core_get_userlink` function

Comment: just curious if my below answer helped or not :-) please let me know so that I may provide additional inputs if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below:

```
function bp_custom_author_link($url, $user_id){

    return "www.xyz.com/my-coustom-page/?id=" . $user_id ;  

}
add_filter( 'bp_core_get_userlink', 'bp_custom_author_link', 10, 2 );
```

I think you can take it further and change the inner logic of the function as intended :-)